# How to ignore some parameter in JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, aop, aspect

I pass arguments to get data from database by JPA.

There are two arguments.
The first argument is ServiceType ; to switch database from Aspect (AOP)
The second argument is used to make query.

However there is org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind error

in conclusion, how to ignore the first(ServiceType) argument to make JPA query.

The code is like that.

```
@Repository
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Integer> {
    List<Blog> findByName(ServiceType serviceType, String name, Pageable pageable);
}


@Aspect
@Order(1)
@Component
public class MDBDecisionAspect {
    private static ThreadLocal<ServiceType> localService = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.test.jpa.mdb..*.*(com.test.enums.ServiceType, ..))")
    public void repositoryAspectTarget() {

    }

    @Around("repositoryAspectTarget()")
    public Object initDaoService(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

        if (args[0] != null && ServiceType.class.equals(args[0].getClass())) {
            setServiceType(((ServiceType) args[0]));
        }

        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }

    @AfterReturning("repositoryAspectTarget()")
    public void afterInitDaoServiceReturningTargetMethod() {
        setServiceType(null);
    }

    public static ServiceType getServiceType() {
        return localService.get();
    }

    public static void setServiceType(ServiceType serviceType) {
        localService.set(serviceType);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. The aspect does nothing but set an internal field which is never used. Also the target class to be intercepted is missing. What is that class doing? And what do you mean by "how to ignore the first(ServiceType) argument to make JPA query"? None of the code you show here makes a JPA query. Please edit the question, creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

create a service class and call repository in it. So you can use serviceType inside service class.

```
@Repository
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Integer> {
    List<Blog> findByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
}

class BlogService{
   public List<Blog> getListOfBlog(ServiceType st, String name){
      blogRepository. findByName(name);
}
}
```

change aspect pointcut to check service class.